# New Imported files aren't compiling to CSS ( NPM Compile:SASS )

Tags: node.js, sass

I am just starting with SASS, completely beginner out there.
The package compile:sass is working perfectly, but problem is whenever I make a new scss file I have to completely restart my SASS compilator and my live-server(package aswell) to actually detect the changes being made into the new file.. Can I fix this, or this is how it works?

Are there better ways to compile SASS?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is how it works. When the SASS compiler starts, it makes a list of `.scss` files that it needs to watch for changes. Any file created after the compiler has started will not be watched for changes.

Well the best preferred way to compile sass it to have a master `.scss` file that gets compiled. And any new file that is created should be created as a partial (that is not compiled to a separate `.css` file).

For eg. I create a file **style.scss** which compiles to **style.css**. Now suppose I want to create a file for forms, so I create `_forms.scss` and import this file in the **style.scss**.

Files that start with `_` are called partials and they are not compiled to a separate `.css` file. But yes, use this the way it is supposed to be used, i.e. **create a partial file only when the styles included in the partial file is a part of some master file** and it itself is not a standalone scss file.

**_forms.scss**

```
.input {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**style.scss:**

```
@import "path_to/form";
.body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: calibri;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am doing this the same way. I have main.scss and partial scss files but still it does not detect the new one after importing it.

Comment: Now this is not an expected behaviour. I've worked with `node-sass` in command-line, gulp and webpack and I never faced this problem. I've never used compile:SASS. Can you try it over node-sass.

Comment: No, its just how i named the script -- compile:SASS but the package itself is node-sass

Comment: Thanks, Didn't realize I had to restart the sass transpiler after creating new partials.